# Why does iframe have the server make a request not client

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, tomcat, iframe, internet-explorer-8

I  have a structure like this
 jsp/iframe/jsp/img src=servlet

In the access logs it shows the server's ip address making the servlet request not the
client? Servlet address is a context variable of a cluster address the client is on a sticky 
session to particular server but the iframe is not and session data is not there if it gets to the other server.

Tomcat 6 and IE8

Thanks

```
Server #1 log
192.**.***.*** - agt**** [01/Jun/2012:09:23:55 -0500] "POST /membership
/GenerateSignatureServlet HTTP/1.1" 200 34

192.**.***.*** - agt**** [01/Jun/2012:09:23:55 -0500] "GET /membership
/printpage.jsp?type=newmem&trh=false HTTP/1.1" 200 997

192.**.***.*** - agt**** [01/Jun/2012:09:23:55 -0500] "GET /membership/js/newmember.js
HTTP/1.1" 304 -
192.**.***.*** - agt**** [01/Jun/2012:09:23:55 -0500] "GET /membership/js/prototype- 
1.6.0.2.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
192.**.***.*** - agt**** [01/Jun/2012:09:23:55 -0500] "GET /membership/theme
/FBMembership.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
192.**.***.*** - agt**** [01/Jun/2012:09:23:55 -0500] "GET /membership/dhtmlmodal
/windowfiles/dhtmlwindow.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
192.**.***.*** - agt**** [01/Jun/2012:09:23:55 -0500] "GET /membership/theme 
/signature.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
192.**.***.*** - agt**** [01/Jun/2012:09:23:55 -0500] "GET /membership
/signaturepageprint.jsp?trh=false HTTP/1.1" 200 51441

Server #2 log
172.**.***.*** - agt**** [01/Jun/2012:09:23:56 -0500] "GET /membership  


/GenerateSignatureServlet;jsessionid=91FFBB3EAA73F3833BA507B7B9B6B317?
action=generateSigImg     HTTP/1.1" 200 39466


Back to server #1
192.***.***.*** - agt**** [01/Jun/2012:09:23:58 -0500] "POST /membership/MoveToFileNet?action=mainprocess&type=mainprocess HTTP/1.1" 200 9
```

Comment: This question is very poorly-written.

What does "jsp/iframe/jsp/img src" mean? Are your JSPs performing any includes within them?

Comment: Sorry might look poorly written, I was just trying to short hand it o It means I have a jsp with an iframe tag inside of it and inside the iframe tag there is a src and the src is another jsp, the last jsp has the img tag and it's src is a servlet to write out a signature image.

Comment: I know it doesn't sound like a good plan, but the first jsp is loaded with ajax which then loads the iframe. We went with the iframe to help focus the user and "veil out" the rest of the app. The jsp that is the src for the iframe is for the agreement we generate, we have a signature pad with js and the user clicks a button to activate the sig pad, then signs it. This is inside a form, the form is submitted to a servlet to capture the signature.

Comment: After it is capture the servlet response and the next jsp is loaded with ajax, this jsp is actually turn into a pdf with pd4hml, it has an img src tag to a servlet to generate the signature image that was captured on the pdf for user to have a legal copy of the agreement for the customer to have.

Comment: Okay, I think I get all that, now... its a pretty standard "please sign this agreement" page with some AJAX thrown in for fun, plus a PDF for some reason. So, which "src" attribute issues a query that appears to come from the server?

Comment: Christopher, it is the "src" on the last jsp, it points to a cluster addressed servlet. This jsp is inside the iframe, which I think might be the cause of the situation.

Comment: I have posted some of the Access logs, the server #2 log is showing the cluster address making the call to the servlet not the client.  We have changed the cluster address in the imp src tag to the servlet to be a localhost. Seems to working this morning ,but this problem still bugs me

Answer (score 0):

If you have a server-based component that consumes HTML and generates a PDF from that markup, then requesting the PDF from the server will likely cause the server to turn-around and make a loop-back request to itself (or another member in the cluster for that matter) in order to fetch the HTML.

If you don't like seeing log messages that show the cluster "calling itself", you have a few options that I can think of:

1. When the PDF-generator calls-out to fetch the HTML, provide proxy-related HTTP headers so that the server handling the request for HTML logs the request, it looks like its coming from somewhere else (like the client). Note that ops folks might not like this option because the request *really did* come from inside the cluster and now from the outside.
2. Modify your log (or connector) settings so that these loopback requests are logged in a different way. If you use a separate connector, you can get localhost communication speed and completely avoid HTTPS performance hits if you use HTTPS. Or, you can log those loopback requests somewhere else so they don't "pollute" your logs.
3. Re-work your workflow for generating the PDF by creating the HTML markup without making an HTTP request. If you are using JSP, this will probably be a tall order since you'd have to get the JSP compiler/runner working outside the context of an HTTP request which wasn't how it was designed.

What's the problem with having these requests logged in such a way, anyway?

Comment: Christopher,  I don't have any problems with the logs, just attached the logs to show, my main problem is the data that  the servlet needs to generate the src img is in a session and when the request is made to the opposite server we will get a null pointer because the session is only on the first server, we have implement session sharing between the cluster ,but I still want to solve the root problem. Thanks for taking the time to look into it.

Comment: The server is sending the sessionid path info parameter when making the request (that's the ";jsessionid=..." part) and so you should be getting the same session no matter which member of the cluster you are contacting. Are you using distributed sessions or are you using stick sessions (or both, I guess)? When making the loopback request (back to the cluster), are you using the same IP/hostname as the load-balancer or what? How does the loopback request determine which server to contact? IMO, "localhost" is the best decision here for a number of reasons.

Comment: We put the 'localhost' in production this morning haven't seen problems as of yet. We used both Tomcat delta manager to share sessions and sticky sessions are controlled by our network switch, the loopback is using the cluster address if I understand that correctly. I think that is part of the problem the loopback doesn't know which one because the switch is going by ip and the client is not making the request so it lost its "sticky" . Do you know of any foreseen problems  with using "locahost", since the client is using a cluster address and we switch to another url or localhost?

Comment: If the loopback request includes the jsessionid in the request, then a load-balancer should be able to choose the right backend server. I'll bet I know what's going on: your load balancer (switch?) is configured to choose the backend server based upon the JSESSIONID cookie but *not* the ";jsessionid=..." pathinfo from the URL. Try adding the cookie to the loopback request (or properly configuring your lb) and see if that helps. You really ought to configure the lb properly otherwise your site won't work properly without cookies enabled.